# Android performance/issues with Corona SDK?

Tags: corona-sdk

I know this is a fairly broad question. We are looking to develop a mobile game and want to use a multi-platform engine/SDK. We like what we see with Corona but in doing some reading, we are seeing a lot of references to poor performance on the 'droid platforms. I am unsure how much of this is still relevant? Many of the articles/posts/references/discussions vary in date from 18 months ago to earlier this year.

Is there a reason we should not pursue Corona if Android support is important to us?

The game is going to be 2D isometric view. Thanks!

Comment: in my opinion if you want to do something like that just use something like http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/ and if you complain about performances you have to code your own engine or learn how to compile from the source supposing that you have the source for a good engine. There are also other engines but libgdx is one of the most popular.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @user827992, but we require an engine/SDK that can support iOS and Android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have worked with Corona Labs (creators of the Corona SDK) as a contractor for almost 2 years now and I can safely tell you that the majority of these issues have been resolved - Android performance has taken a lot of work to improve but it is at the stage now it's very, very solid and the threads from 18 months ago, 12 months ago and even 6 months ago can be largely disregarded. (For more info you can look at build notes summary, you will see many tweaks and improvements to Android.)

Some Android devices will always suffer poor performance, be that with a Corona made app or a native app. There are a lot of dirt cheap devices out there and having toyed with these fairly extensively myself (I develop for Android and iOS personally and for clients) I can tell you that these are going to be a problem regardless, they just aren't powerful enough for games.

Of course, Corona has an unlimited free trial so you can also test on your own Android devices without any money down, simply to see for yourself :-)

Comment: Thanks, @Peach. I appreciate it and was hoping to hear this. BTW, I have enjoyed your tutorials. Thanks!